# How to change product key of Office 2007 / 2010?

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-office-2010, c#

How can I change the product key of an Office 2007 / 2010 and activate it after that in C#?

Comment: @Luís Custódio it's a question for StackOverflow because i want activate the Office with a C# Application

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do this in C# but if you look into what [Magical Jellybean Keyfinder](http://www.magicaljellybean.com/keyfinder/) does (it uses definition files that are pretty easy to read) you could find where MS hides the magic sauce, erm, keys in the registry.

The Keyfinder can change keys as well, so if you're just looking for how to do that, give it a try.